# java - String in GUI are being cut before the ellipsis are appearing. Is there a option I would have to set?

Tags: java, eclipse, ellipsis

I have the following problem in my program which is created in eclipse luna with java 1.8.0

As you can see in the first part of the image the ip address is completely visible. However if you reduce the size of the bar, then the last characters are not shown anymore. (the 77 is missing in the first row) You can see that in the middle part of the image. However I would imagine that the ellipsis would appear directly. But they first appear when I am reducing the bar further on. In the last part of the image you can see that ip address has the ellipsis but the ip address does not. The IP Address would get the ellipsis as well if I would decrease the size more.

Is it a property I would have to set when I am creating the table? Or is it even a feature and not a bug? (For whatever reason)

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using a JTable and the width of the column is decreasing. This is standard behaviour. If there is not enough room to display the entire text the "..." is displayed to give an indicator to the user that there is more text. You can always set a tooltip on the table cell to display the entire text. `the 77 is missing in the first row)` - don't know why the "77" would be missing. You need to post a [mcve] to see if we can spot a problem with the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. 
What I meant with the 77 is that by reducing the size the 77 and the 70 below dissapear. (which you can see if you compare the middle part with the left part. You see what I mean? Of course if I am going with the tooltip over it, it's going to show me the full ip address 192.168.1.177 but how would the user know that the ip address is ending actually with ...177 and not ...1 because there are not ellipsis in  the middle part of  the image. You get what I mean?

Comment: I have never seen the "77" completely disappear. If there is more text to be displayed, then you should see "...". If this isn't happening I have no idea why and you haven't posted a [mcve] that I can test to see if I have the same problem.